# Error - Unable to connect oData service link from SAP HANA CDS VIews to power bi

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, cds

Details: "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:
OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (The request URI contains an invalid key predicate.

I checked the version of eclipse. its 4. but im not sure if thats what matters or whether it has been upgraded from 3 to 4. Any advice or help is much appreciated